# PS3 Controller wont sync wireless and tethered. Is recognised on PC

Tags: ps3, controllers

I have a PS3 controller that will not function at all wireless or tethered. After looking at some troubleshooting I have attempted the reset button on the controller and also done this with console on and off with no success. I thought initially it was destined for the trash can as the only response I see is four lights that blink either 10 or 12 times depending on weather it wireless or tethered. However, when I attached this to my PC via I see it is immediately recognised as a PS3 controller. Just wondering if anyone had experienced anything similar? Or had any trouble shooting advice I can perform with the controller or maybe some PC software to see if it is indeed dead.

Installed motionjoy and ds3 and tested controller, well the vibration test built into the application and it responds. The device is being recognised but just not on the PS3. I have both another Dualshock 3 and 2 move controllers working on the same console so failing to understand where the problem may stand. Would assume it has an issue pairing but does not explain why it's not working tethered.

Comment: It was recognized on PC immediately? PS3 controllers aren't recognized by windows unless you change driver level settings, if it was recognized immediately it isn't a PS3 controller.

Comment: Errm, okay well I am using windows 8.1. I am not really sure what makes you think it's not a PS3 controller but it certainly appears to be and whilst I had not played with it for a while it was bought through a legitimate channel. Further to the USB bus request the device entry is identified as a PS3 controller, I am not calibrating or playing any games with it, it's simply identified as such.

Comment: Aah, identified. Yeah it'll do that. From recognized I figured you meant it was recognized as a gamepad and not some vague unknown object calling itself a "PS3 controller". While you *can* get windows to recognize it as a gamepad you need a couple of extra steps.

Comment: Hence why I am seeking some windows based software to troubleshoot. Although bit conscious that this will just emulate but would be good to know buttons are indeed functioning.

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden Windows will recognize it as a standard USB game controller without any additional steps or software. It just won't work if you try to use it. The PS3 controller is a normal USB HID device that doesn't need any special support except for one little thing. It needs to be sent a special command before it will report which buttons on the controller are being pushed. That's what the third party drivers do to allow PS3 controllers to work  Unsigned versions of these drivers require that you change certain settings, but signed versions don't.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a new controller? If so, try to tether it to the PS3 while the PS3 is on and press the PlayStation button on the controller. Then it should get registered by the PS3 and the controller should be usable.

Comment: Unfortunately not, not used it in sometime and have tried but no love. Thanks for the advice however.

Comment: @OhKnowHeDidnt2 Try a different USB cable or different USB port on the PS3.